# DynamoDB limit for 20 projected attributes in indexes - workaround?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I just came across another fun hard-limit on dynamoDB.
This time it is a maximum of 20 projected attributes on all indexes (gsi/lsi) created for a table.
As weird as this number is (not even a power of 2 ), they can't seem to lift this limit. Looking for good ideas of how I can overcome this efficiently.
My main problem is that my table contains one very fat column, which slows down scans significantly. Thought of even writing a copy of each record to a second table.
I need to create a few indexes 
Looking for clever ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [DynamoDB Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/) and [cross-region replication](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library) to create table replicas in the same region. Then, add GSI to the replicas with a different subset of projected attributes. Regarding the fat column, I recommend evacuating the column to S3 and storing a link to the data in each DynamoDB item.